# I want to return the combined result of two tables in a consolidated table

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I want to combine two tables into one table using MS Access

I have the following two tables in MS Access:

```
LEDGER_1
LEDGER_2
```

Both tables have a reference field.

I want to combine the two table into one table using a query.

I have tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO T_RECON ( REFERENCE )
SELECT REFERENCE
FROM LEDGER_1
UNION
SELECT REFERENCE
FROM LEDGER_2;
```

I keep getting a SYNTAX error

I just want to combine the result of the two tables with my query

Comment: I have tried this. I still get a SYNTAX error. This will also become an issue if I want to  insert more than one field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT INTO` will work only if the table `T_RECON` already exists and contains a column `REFERENCE`.
Wrap the `UNION`ed queries inside another query:

```
INSERT INTO T_RECON (REFERENCE)
SELECT REFERENCE
FROM (
  SELECT REFERENCE
  FROM LEDGER_1
  UNION
  SELECT REFERENCE
  FROM LEDGER_2
)
```

Comment: Thank you. What you are saying makes a lot of sense. However, when using the query as provided by you I get the following error:

Syntax error in FROM clause

I can also confirm that my table has been created. I am able to populate my query into that table with no issues when I am using one table only. The moment I am combining the second table I start getting these errors

Comment: Is this the exact code that you use? Because if it is then it should run without syntax error. I tested it.

Comment: Ok, I had a semicolon, removed it try now

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Question: If Table 1 and Table 2 have duplicate references, will it appear in duplicate here? Or will it remove the duplicate values? I would like to see the duplicate values appear twice

Comment: UNION removes duplicates. If you want duplicates use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

If the table doesn't exist, you need to create it:

```
SELECT REFERENCE
INTO T_RECON
FROM LEDGER_1
UNION
SELECT REFERENCE
FROM LEDGER_2;
```

Actually, I'm not 100% sure if MS Access accepts this.  You might need a subquery:

```
SELECT REFERENCE
INTO T_RECON
FROM (SELECT REFERENCE FROM LEDGER_1
      UNION
      SELECT REFERENCE FROM LEDGER_2
     ) as L
```